# Interview Coding - Take a pointer to a Node structure as a parameter and return a complete copy of the passed-in data structure

Tags: c++

This is an interview question that I found interesting.

Write a method that takes a pointer to a Node structure as a parameter and returns a complete copy of the passed-in data structure.

The Node structure contains two pointers to other Node structures.
For example, the method signature could look like so:

```
Node* Copy(Node* root);
```

---

**Note** -  Do not make any assumptions about the data structure – it could be a tree, linked list, graph, etc.

*How can this be done for any data structure ?*

Comment: Not mine, but see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask .

Comment: @MSalters Apologies ! I do understand that. I have been breaking my head with this, and I wanted to get this question out on StackOverflow. I had no intention of violating the StackOverflow policy.

Comment: @Legolas I've spent quite a lot of time trying to understand the question, but couldn't get it. Would it be possible for you to elaborate a bit on the question ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the generic graph case, you need a mapping from nodes in the original graph to nodes in the new graph, so that when a cycle is encountered, the proper link gets created.  If you happen to have extra temporary space in each node, large enough to hold a pointer, then you can store the mapping directly in the nodes; otherwise, you'll need to use an external map, such as an associative array or hash table.

Then it's just a matter of traversing the graph, copying nodes, and looking up the corresponding edges.  Something like this:

```
struct Node
{
    Node(int _data) : data(_data) { memset(links, 0, sizeof(links)); }

    int data;
    Node *links[2];
}

Node *Copy(Node *root)
{
    typedef std::map<Node*, Node*> NodeMap;
    NodeMap nodeMap;
    std::deque<Node*> nodesToVisit;

    // Set up initial new root and mapping for the root
    Node *newRoot = new Node(root->data);
    nodeMap[root] = newRoot;

    // Breadth-first search the graph
    nodesToVisit.push_back(root);

    while(!nodesToVisit.empty())
    {
        Node *cur = nodesToVisit.front();
        nodesToVisit.pop_front();

        Node *newCur = nodeMap[cur];
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Node *link = cur->links[i];
            if(link)
            {
                // If we've already created the corresponding node for this
                // link, use that.  Otherwise, create it and add it to the map.
                NodeMap::iterator mappedLink = nodeMap.find(link);
                if(mappedLink != nodeMap.end())
                {
                    newCur->links[i] = mappedLink->second;
                }
                else
                {
                    Node *newLink = new Node(link->data);
                    nodeMap[link] = newLink;
                    newCur->links[i] = newLink;
                    nodesToVisit.push_back(link);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return newRoot;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to `push_back(link)` at the end, since `nodesToVisit` contains pointers to nodes in the old structure, not the new one.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I know this is a very old question, but I've spent a lot of time trying to understand the question and your answer to it. In particular, I couldn't understand what you meant by this: ` so that when a cycle is encountered, the proper link gets created.` I'd appreciate if you can elaborate a bit. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem as stated is impossible.  You have to assume that the entire data structure is stored entirely within the content of nodes that are accessible from that initial one.  But that is not an assumption you are allowed to make.  Even your standard basic double linked list might not fit that description.

Comment: Technically, of course, the data structure is a directed graph with two out-vertices per node; you just state that you can't copy a forest given a single root. If you understand copying a root as copying only the tree, not the forest, then this is possible. And yes, it requires a root.

Comment: I want to +1, but surely in a doubly-linked list, the whole structure *is* accessible from any node? If it isn't, then it isn't a doubly-linked list, it's something else.

Comment: @Steve: The whole structure is accessible, but there can be additional data lacking, such as an extra pointer to the two ends.  However, looking at MSalters comment, and rereading the question, perhaps I'm misinterpreting.  I took `the data structure` to mean `the data structure the node is a part of` rather than `the data structure defined by the node`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Agreed, meta-data (and for that matter the type of any surrounding data structure object of which the node is part) can't be determined. I'm pretty sure that what the original interview question will have been after, is a clone of the set of nodes reachable from this node, with all corresponding edges. But that's not certain from the version of the question we see here.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Copier {
  std::map <Node*, Node*> copies;

  Node* Copy(Node* n) {
    if (!n) return 0;
    Node*& copy = copies[n];
    if (!copy) {
      copy = new Node();
      copy.node1 = Copy(n.node1);
      copy.node2 = Copy(n.node2);
    }
    return copy;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not C++, but not bad.  It's incorrect though, it might add one extra Node.

Comment: oh, I missed the C++ tag; I thought I was the last living C++ programmer :-)

Comment: This adds a "NULL" node.  Then segfaults.

Comment: Looks OK except that it should be `copy->node1 = Copy(n->node1);` and the same for 2. Plus, this recurses O(n) deep in the worst case, which is worrying. Oh, and `Copy` probably ought to be public ;-)

Comment: @Steve: excellent point about the recursion depth.  So *that's* why other posters use a queue.

Answer (score 2):

```
Node* Copy(Node* root) {
   if (root == NULL)
       return root;
   std::unordered_map<Node*, Node*> completed; 
   std::deque<Node*> todo;
   Node *ret = new Node(*scur);
   completed.push_back(std::make_pair(root, ret));
   todo.push_pack(root); 

   //while there's more nodes to duplicate
   do { 
       //duplicate the node
       Node* oldNode = todo.back();
       Node* newNode = completed[cur];
       todo.pop_back();

       if(oldNode->left) {
           auto iter = completed.find(oldNode->left);
           //if it has a left child that needs duplicating, add it to the todo list
           if (iter == completed.end()) {
               newNode->left = new Node(*(oldNode->left));
               completed.push_back(std::make_pair(oldNode->left, newNode->left));
               todo.push_back(oldNode->left);
           } else {
               newNode->left = completed[oldNode->left];
           }
       }
       if(oldNode->right) {
           auto iter = completed.find(oldNode->right);
           //if it has a right child that needs duplicating, add it to the todo list
           if (iter == completed.end()) {
               newNode->right = new Node(*(oldNode->right));
               completed.push_back(std::make_pair(oldNode->right, newNode->right));
               todo.push_back(oldNode->right);
           } else {
               newNode->right= completed[oldNode->right];
           }
       }

   } while(todo.empty() == false)
   //return the translation of the root
   return ret;
}
```

Doesn't have stack overflow, root can be NULL, doesn't fail if left or right are NULL.

[Edit]Adam Rosenfield made me realize this was incorrect if there was loops in the network.  Had to rewrite almost from scratch.  Due to the large amount of code required, I prefer his code's for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
return new Node(*node);
```

Trick question?

Comment: I do not think so. I think the problem is related with Deep Copy and Shallow Copy.

Comment: @Legolas That depends on how the copy-constructor is defined.

Comment: I think the question is supposed to distinguish between the "Node structure" and the "data structure". You've copied the former, but my psychic intuition is that the real interview question isn't after that, and that `Node` is just a POD-struct containing two pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You should write it recursively;

```
Node * Copy( Node * root )
{
    Node * node_copy;

    node_copy = new Node; // Assume Node1 and Node2 are initialized to 0
    node_copy->content = root->content;

    if( root->Node1 ) node_copy->Node1 = Copy( root->Node1 );
    if( root->Node2 ) node_copy->Node2 = Copy( root->Node2 );

    return node_copy;
}
```

So, this does not make any assumption on the data type

Comment: `Node n = new Node(); n.node1 = n.node2 = n; Copy(n);` could take a long time.

Comment: Yes it will. If you need to handle that case, you need to store pair of source node/new node and search for the node first in that table. If you find it, set the pointer, if it isn't there, just clone it and add it to the list

Comment: @xrazyjul: I think that is required, since the question says the full data structure might be a "graph". If it just said it might be a DAG you could assume no cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Given that a copy constructor exists that copies only the contents of a node and not its children:

```
Node* Copy(Node* root)
{
    Node* copy = new Node(*root);
    copy->left = Copy(root->left);
    copy->right = Copy(root->right);
    return copy;
}
```

In a more general sense, I would use copy-constructors that fully copy the entire data structure:

```
Node* Copy(Node* root)
{
    return new Node(*root);
}
```

Comment: and if it's a doubly linked list that leads to stack overflow.  Also, dereferencing of NULL pointers.  Whichever happens first.